# Reorder legend and bars for grouped bar chart

Tags: r, r-markdown, refactoring, forcats

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r99dB.png)Using Rmarkdown printing to a PDF.

I have created a macro function, but am having trouble correcting the order of my legend for grouped bar charts.

The data table created has 4 columns. 
1-  location: (Spain, Portugal, Ukraine)
2- Agreement levels: (Strongly Agree, Agree, Disagree, Strongly Disagree, Missing)
3- ID levels that correspond to the agreement levels (1, 2, 3, 4, and 0 is for missing)
4- Count values

I would like to create a grouped bar chart (grouping by location) and plot the count values for each agreement level.

NOTE!! Since this is a macro function occasionally the agreement levels can change to something like satisfaction levels (extremely unsatisfied, unsatisfied, satisfied, extremely satisfied). This is why I include the id numeric levels.

My issue is that I can not order my legend/ grouped bar charts in order.

I am able to use the ID levels for the ordering, but then my legend only displays numbers which is not useful. I need the legend to display what the numbers represent (1= strongly Agree, 2= Agree ext)

Is there a way to order my levels by the id (0,1,2,3,4) but display their values?

I have tried forcats, reorder, factor/levels, groupby ... but still don't seem to get the correct output

Attached are some images of my current output, but as shown I still need to correct the levels/legend order.

```
macrofunction <- function(df_table) {
plots = ggplot(df_table, aes(x=location, y=as.numeric(df_table$Value), fill=levels)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) }
```

Comment: Any idea if the following is on the right track: scale_fill_discrete(name="legend title", breaks=levels(df_table$id), labels = df_table$levels)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that was interested, I took a different approach to solve the problem. 
I ended up using facet_wrap to get around the issue.

plots = ggplot(df_table, aes(x=id, y=as.numeric(df_table$Value), fill=Response)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(~ location) +